# Searching object with recursive function in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, function, search, recursion, coffeescript

This is my first post on StackOverflow.  Greetings!

I am an absolute beginner programmer learning JavaScript and CoffeeScript.

I am writing a recursive function to search through an object simply as a learning exercise.

What I expect the function to do:

1. Pass the function an object and an item.
2. It returns "item found" if the item exists.
3. It returns "item not found" if the item does not exist.

What it currently does:

1. Pass the function an object and an item.
2. It returns "item not found" even though the item exists.

Here is my CoffeeScript:

```
meats =
        a: "chickens"
        b: "bacons"
        c: "hams"
        d: "salamis"
        e: "beefs"

meatSearch = (dict, key) ->
        if dict is key
        then console.log "found #{dict.item}"
        else if dict.sub
        then meatSearch dict.sub, key
        else console.log "item not found"

meatSearch meats, "b"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about try something like this [using javascript, not coffee sorry]:

```
var index = 0;
var meats = {
    0:'chickens',
    1:'bacons',
    2:'hams',
    3:'salamis',
    4:'beefs'
};

searchMeats: function(object, item) {
    console.log(object,item);
    if (object[index] === item) {
        console.log('found ' + item);
    } else if (object[index+1]) {
        delete object[index];
        index = index + 1;
        searchMeats(object, item);
    } else {
        console.log('item not found');
    }
};
searchMeats(meats, "hams");
```

It's not super beautiful, but it uses recursion!

Comment: Thank you!  I converted this code into CS [link](http://paste.ofcode.org/hrC5NNaS4qnj98t9A4TcHL).  What is the purpose of the "delete object[index] line?  The code seems to work without it.  Is it possible for this to work without a global variable?

Comment: The "delete" line is only so you don't keep throwing the same object into the next round of recursiveness.  It deletes the value with name 'index' [deletes item 0 - 'chickens' then 1 - 'bacons'].  So yes, the function works without deleting, but it is less recursive without it!

Comment: Yes, it would work without the global variable 'index' - I would probably pass another variable to the function that keeps track of what index you're on - and therefore start the recursion with searchMeats(meats, "hams", 0);  Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks again for the help!  I have the new code up here [link](http://paste.ofcode.org/NPbayGjwMrzEzBVs5c37Pk).  Now down to 4 lines using only recursion!  =)

Comment: Groovy, glad it works!  Good luck in your learning adventures!

Answer (score 1):

first of all I think the example data should be more recursive. There is just one layer and it will be hard to **recurse**

second: It is not clear why you search for an item (that is a key value pair) and what you expect as a return value. So I changed your example slightly to return the value that is defined on an key

```
meats =
    a: "chickens"
    b: 
        b1: "bacon"
        b2: "Schinken"
        b3: "Sunka"
    s: 
        s1: "French Salami"
        s2: "Italian Salami"
    e: "beefs"

search = (dict, key) ->
    #check if dict is not an object and return imediately
    return null if dict != Object(dict)

    #get value of key
    result = dict[key]
    # return value if key is found
    return result if result

    #else iterate over keys and call search recursively for the value
    for k of dict
        console.log "#{k}: #{dict[k]}"
        result = search dict[k], key
        # return as soon as something is found
        return result if result

    #return null if nothing found
    return null

    console.log search meats, "b3" #should return <<Sunka>>
```

Comment: This is very good!  I get some strange behavior from this code it outputs "a: chickens b: [object] [object] Sunka".  I can see the reason for using a for loop with the recursion in your example.  My goal however is to get the code working with purely recursion and hopefully understand it as well.  Thank you for the great post though it was extremely helpful!

Comment: There is a console.log in the for loop. you cant simply delete that. You could use an Object.keys(dict).forEach and then a call back. However internally within forEach there is a loop even the purest functional language uses iteration within ;-) plus the for loop gives you the possibility to break out of the loop as soon as you found a matching key.